# knockout.js binding selectbox

Tags: binding, knockout.js, drop-down-menu

I'm fiddling around with knockout js and trying to make a grid with a select in it.
It looks i'm a bit stuck here.

I would like to bind an array to the selectbox gridrow and after clicking the save (S) i would like to see an json response like

{ id: 2, name: "Long Cloak", price: "120.20", selthis: 1 }

here's what i got http://jsfiddle.net/marsmania00/JS6An/
any help would be appreciated!

regards,
michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were binding the list of options to the wrong level. the list of options is in $root.pulldown for your use case. See http://jsfiddle.net/JS6An/2/

Comment: How about an accept to go with the upvote? It makes your questions more likely to get positive attention in the future.